# Run separate nodejs file from PhantomJS / CasperJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, phantomjs, casperjs

I'm trying to execute a nodejs script from CasperJS. This should be possible from the PhantomJS `childprocess` library. But it doesn't seem to be working for me. It's not giving any errors, but it's not executing the node script either. Because that script sends out a push notification. When I run the script directly from command then it works fine. But not from my CasperJS script.

```
var childProc = require("child_process");

var casper = require('casper').create({
    viewportSize: {width: 800, height: 400}
});
var utils = require("utils");

casper.start('http://www.google.com', function() {
    this.echo('Home page opened');
    this.echo(this.getTitle());
    childProc.execFile('C:\\Google Drive\\nodejs\\push.js', [], null, function (err, stdout, stderr){});

    this.exit();
});
```

Anyone any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: @ArtjomB.doesnt seem to work either

Answer (score 0):

You have two problems:

- You forgot to add the command for execution
- You're exiting too early, because `execFile` is an asynchronous function.

Try:

```
casper.start('http://www.google.com', function() {
    this.echo('Home page opened');
    this.echo(this.getTitle());
    childProc.execFile('C:\\Google Drive\\nodejs\\push.js', [], null, function (err, stdout, stderr){
        utils.dump(arguments);
        casper.echo("Exiting..."):
        casper.exit();
    });
}).run(function(){/* This prevents CasperJS from exiting */});
```

Comment: I forgot to add the `casperjs.run()` method in my code snippet, but I had  that. I tried your exact code, but it's still not executing my script. I even placed a `fs.exists()` to make sure the path to `push.js` is correct. Bot the script doesn't seem to get executed.

Comment: Have you tried a simple node script which only prints something to the console?